# How to analyze "the handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format " inner exception

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010, soapexception

I send some data to a web service. But the web service returns a soap exception which has the "handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format" inner exception. How can I know which packet is unexpected? Because I send a few packets to web service. Do you know somewhere in exception message in catch block to find which packet is wrong?

Çağın